# PIC MCC i2c HT16K33 problems

Tags: pic, i2c, led, microchip, xc8

Has anyone out there successfully driven an HT16K33 using MCC i2c generated code?
Using my own rudimentary i2c code I can get the HT16K33(link below) to work ok but no matter what I try the MCC i2c code will not work. As a sanity check I have the MCC code working ok with a PCF8574 io expander.
I am testing with a 16F18877 on a breadboard, no schematic, the HT16K33 is on an Adafruit board(link below), all is verified working with my i2c code and the io expander.
The HT16K33 is an LED controller. Requires three i2c commands to test, turn on oscillator, turn on display, and send data to the display ram. Holtek recommends having a 100ms delay at the program entry to allow the chip to start up which I have before any i2c commands. I have boiled this down to the simplest possible test of the MCC code by using my working code for the display on and ram data, only using the MCC code to start the oscillator which is the first step.

```
I2C1_MESSAGE_STATUS status = I2C1_MESSAGE_PENDING;
I2C1_MasterWrite( 0b00100001, 1, 0x70, &status); 
while (I2C1_MESSAGE_PENDING  == status);
```

http://www.holtek.com/documents/10179/116711/HT16K33v120.pdf
https://learn.adafruit.com/assets/32012

Any ideas?